WPF moniker/images not showing in design view
I'm developing a Visual Studio extension, using the CrispImage UIElement and the monikers feature as per here. However, despite displaying at runtime, they don't at design time. Also tested this in a test new project - same issue. An example of the xaml (with any Styles remove):
<ToolBarTray x:Name="TopToolbar" DockPanel.Dock="Left" Background="Transparent">
    <ToolBar >
        <Button ToolTip="Refresh" Command="{Binding RefreshCommand}">
            <imaging:CrispImage Width="16" Height="16" Moniker="{x:Static catalog:KnownMonikers.Refresh}" />
        </Button>

What I get in designer:

And at runtime:

GitHub code here

You can take a look at my answer, this looks not caused by your code but by some vs broken. :)

Currently looks unable to achieve what you want:
VSSDK/CPS/Extensibility: Image Loading in VS Extensions via .imagemanifest is Broken in VS2022
The extension image issue is still pending on resolving.

Is that definitely monikers or is it more around what the author calls "custom images"?

Appears this is a long neglected and forgotten about bug by MS. I made a workaround via the following.
For each moniker you use, use the KnownMonikers Explorer, find that moniker and download that file (via double click) to a Resources location (I save mine at 32x32 just to make them look pretty in Designer view on zoom!).
Then create a ResourceDictionary with both a reference to the Moniker and the .png version of it:
<ResourceDictionary xmlns:blah...
                    xmlns:imaging="clr-namespace:Microsoft.VisualStudio.Imaging;assembly=Microsoft.VisualStudio.Imaging"
                    xmlns:catalog="clr-namespace:Microsoft.VisualStudio.Imaging;assembly=Microsoft.VisualStudio.ImageCatalog">
        
    <imaging:CrispImage x:Key="UiLogInUserImage" Width="16" Height="16" Moniker="{x:Static catalog:KnownMonikers.LoginUser}" />
    <Image              x:Key="UILogInUserImageDT" Width="16" Height="16" Source="../DesignTimeImages/LoginUser.png"/>
    
</ResourceDictionary>

Import your ResourceDictionary as ever..
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <!-- STYLES -->
            <ResourceDictionary Source="../Resources/Styles/TextBlock.xaml" />
            <!-- MEDIA -->
            <ResourceDictionary Source="../Resources/Media/UiImages.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>

Then use Expression Blend to include the design-time version of the image:
 <!-- xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" -->

<Button x:Name="AuthenticateBT" Content="{StaticResource UiLogInUserImage}"
                                d:Content="{DynamicResource UILogInUserImageDT}">
</Button>

And Bob's your grandma's daughter's brother, one image:

